# How can I access certain field information of a BBDB3 record?

Tags: bbdb

I'd like to write a command so that for a particular record (found for example with `(bbdb-search (bbdb-records) regexp)`) I'm able to extract just the name part of it (or e. g. the mail part, or any part of the xfields). How would you lisp this?

Comment: I think you could use `bbdb-search-prog` with your own function as an argument. That function would need be called with a record looked up, and whenever you think that the record matches, it would need to return the record, in case it accepts it as a potential match.

Comment: Hi @wvxvw, sorry I was not clear enough.  `bbdb-search` is just fine for me, no need for `bbdb-search-prog`.  But I want to know how to extract for a found record for example the www part or the mail-alias...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are accessor functions in bbdb3 for extracting certain part of the record:

```
(bbdb-record-name record)
(bbdb-record-firstname record)
(bbdb-record-lastname record)
...
```

They are defined in bbdb.el